# Basic Features is currently unavailable - Dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

We have recently upgraded our DNN site from 6.0.3 to 7.4.2 version.

The upgrade went successfully. But recently we are getting the following exception when we login to the site and click on the Admin menu option.

> Error: Basic Features is currently unavailable.
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: String was not
>   recognized as a valid Boolean. ---> System.FormatException: String was
>   not recognized as a valid Boolean. at System.Boolean.Parse(String
>   value) at DesktopModules.Admin.Console.ViewConsole.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

We tried checking our portalsettings table for any "Y" or "N" values, but we did not find any. Not sure which of the records in the portalsettings table require a boolean value apart from following fields below.

Can you please suggest what could, apart from the portalsettings is there any other setting which may causing this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this issue...

The cause was strange though - SQL Injection attack!!!

There is a table "TabModuleSettings" which has SettingName and SettingValue columns. The SettingValue column is expected to store "True", "False" depending upon the SettingName value.

But with a sql injection attack, all the SettingValue rows were updated as below

[image: SQL Injection]

So the module load exceptions were thrown.

[image]